# ifelse statement for more than two conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I know many question are asked about `ifelse`, but I searched and tried a lot but no success, therefore I'm posting question here.

I have a data frame of 10k participants with 8 variables, each variable is coded 0, 1, 9 and NA. I would like to create one variable to summarize all 8 variables.

The condition I want to create is: if one from 8 variables has the value 1, then new variable should be 1, if one has a 9, then return 9, else (all in row are NA or other) return 0.

The code i created is this, but get only 1 and NA:

```
z = with(dt, ifelse(var.1==1|var.2==1|var.3==1|var.4==1|
var.5==1|var.6==1|var.7==1|var.8==1, 1, ifelse(var.1==9|var.2==9|var.3==9|var.4==9|
var.5==9|var.6==9|var.7==9|var.8==9, 9, 0)))
```

Thank you.

Comment: your code seems fine. what does this mean "The code i created is this, but get only 1 and NA". Could you share your expected output? also, a reproducible example with even a few rows will really help.

Comment: output is only 1 and NA, however when i use only first 3 or 4 variables it works fine.

Comment: The logical condition `x==1` returns `TRUE` if x=1, `FALSE` if x!=1, but `NA` if x=NA.

Comment: when the last variable (var.8) is NA it returns to NA or 1 (not 0 or 9). @ jlhoward what do u mean?

Comment: You may want to look into `%in%`

Comment: "if one from 8 variables has the value 1, 9, 0 or NA than new variable should be 1". But in the first part you are only checking: if one of the 8 variables is 1 then new variable is 1. could u clarify? also, if any of the the 8 variables is NA, the output will be NA.

Comment: I've edited it to be a more accurate description of what I think was intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested code in the absence of a data example):

```
 ifelse( rowSums(dt[ , c("var.1","var.2", "var.3", "var.4", "var.5", "var.6", "var.7", 
                         "var.8")]==1, na.rm=TRUE), 1, 
       ifelse(  rowSums(dt[ , c("var.1","var.2", "var.3", "var.4", "var.5", 
                                 "var.6", "var.7", "var.8")]==9, na.rm=TRUE) , 
                 9, 0))
```

There is an implicit coercion of the value 0 to false by the ifelse calls and any value other than 0 is TRUE. The `na.rm=TRUE` keeps the sums from being NA. I suppose you could get into problems if all of the values in a row were NA.

Comment: Thank you, this code works! Interesting how you use rowSum but still get 1 or 9 not the sum... hope you got what I mean.

Comment: `ifelse` coerces the integer sums to TRUE or FALSE.